Windows 11 virtual desktop switch shortcut
In Windows 11, switching to different virtual desktops has the following shortcuts by default:

Alt+Tab+Click
Alt+Tab+Arrow+Enter
Win+Ctrl+Arrow

In the old days, there was a way to customise these shortcuts. What I would like to have is:
Alt+n where n=1,2,3... to switch instantly to the n-th virtual desktop.
Is this possible? How?
EDIT
Maybe my settings.ini is not sound:
[General]
DefaultDesktop=1
TaskbarScrollSwitching=1
UseNativePrevNextDesktopSwitchingIfConflicting=0
DesktopWrapping=1

[Tooltips]
Enabled=1
; One of LEFT, CENTER, RIGHT
PositionX=CENTER
; One of TOP, CENTER, BOTTOM
PositionY=CENTER
FontSize=11
FontColor=0xFFFFFF
FontInBold=1
BackgroundColor=0x1F1F1F
Lifespan=750
; Watch out! Long durations (> 500ms) could cause troubles as the program freezes during the animation.
FadeOutAnimationDuration=100
OnEveryMonitor=1

[KeyboardShortcutsCombinations]
TogglePinWindow=Win, Ctrl, Shift, Q
TogglePinApp=Win, Ctrl, Shift, A
PinWindow=
PinApp=
UnpinWindow=
UnpinApp=
; "SC029" is the key below your "Esc" key
OpenDesktopManager=LAlt, SC029
ChangeDesktopName=Win, F2

[KeyboardShortcutsModifiers]
SwitchDesktop=Win, Ctrl
MoveWindowToDesktop=
MoveWindowAndSwitchToDesktop=Win, Ctrl, Shift
NextTenDesktops=

[KeyboardShortcutsIdentifiers]
PreviousDesktop=Left
NextDesktop=Right
Desktop1=1
Desktop2=2
Desktop3=3
Desktop4=4
Desktop5=5
Desktop6=6
Desktop7=7
Desktop8=8
Desktop9=9
Desktop10=0
DesktopAlt1=Numpad1
DesktopAlt2=Numpad2
DesktopAlt3=Numpad3
DesktopAlt4=Numpad4
DesktopAlt5=Numpad5
DesktopAlt6=Numpad6
DesktopAlt7=Numpad7
DesktopAlt8=Numpad8
DesktopAlt9=Numpad9
DesktopAlt10=Numpad0

[Wallpapers]
1=
2=
3=
4=
5=
6=
7=
8=
9=
10=

[DesktopNames]
1=
2=
3=
4=
5=
6=
7=
8=
9=
10=

[RunProgramWhenSwitchingToDesktop]
1=
2=
3=
4=
5=
6=
7=
8=
9=
10=

[RunProgramWhenSwitchingFromDesktop]
1=
2=
3=
4=
5=
6=
7=
8=
9=
10=



Does this answer your question? How to change shortcut key for switching between virtual desktops in windows 10 or windows 11?

I tried zVirtualDesktop and this tool actually works as I need:
https://github.com/mzomparelli/zVirtualDesktop

Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Check out this post.

Download and unzip this Windows 10 Virtual Desktop Enhancer
Replace VirtualDesktopAccessor.dll with file from here
Run virtual-desktop-enhancer.exe as administrator.
Edit the [KeyboardShortcutsModifiers] section in settings.ini if necessary. Default for switching between VirtualDesktops are Win+Ctrl+1/2/3/n.


I tried, it doesn't work (nothing happens when I activate the keystroke)

Yeah, replacing a file from Windows 10 onto Windows 11 was never going to work.

Running on Win11 22H2 and it worked for me. ¯\(ツ)/¯ If the tool is activated, you should temporarily see a 1 when starting the executable. Did you change the file name? Cause the original file was named virtual-desktop-accessor.dll, while the replacement had no dashes.

@Ramhound What make you say that? The solution seem to have worked in the other post, as it did for me. In the new VirtualDesktopAccessor.dll Github exist discussions regarding compatibility with Win11.

@IHadAFish - The clone of the repository does not mention any of that. The description of the clone of the repository only references Windows 10.

@IHadAFish Yes I changed the name and overwrote the DLL. Didn't see any "1" when starting the exe. The exe was definitely running (visible in task manager), and also it broke the windows default keystrokes for virtual-desktop switching. Only killing it restores them

@FrancoTiveron That's unfortunate. Although there should be a icon for it at the bottom right corner, so task manager shouldn't be necessary. The only thing I can think of is that, this tool won't actually create a new desktop for you, so maybe try to create an extra one first? If that doesn't work, then I'm out of ideas.

@Ramhound It's the page in step two, please check this link: https://github.com/skottmckay/VirtualDesktopAccessor/discussions

@IHadAFish Maybe my settings are incorrect. Is there some documentation about the settings.ini file?

@FrancoTiveron This is the original documentation: https://github.com/sdias/win-10-virtual-desktop-enhancer/blob/master/docs/settings.md There's also some other default hotkeys, LAlt+~ should open the desktop manager, while Win+F2 should open a prompt for changing the desktop's name. If the other keys also doesn't work, adjusting the ini file probably won't help. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

@FrancoTiveron A slightly different solution, also using Autohotkeys: https://github.com/pmb6tz/windows-desktop-switcher
